# Add tag html <a> on datatable Ajax sourced data

Tags: html, ajax, datatable, datatables

I use add tag link in basic sourced data which it work.

```
<td><a href="review/data.html?id=<?php echo $_POST['id'] ?>">Action</a></td>
```

But i not work to Ajax sourced data in add tag html

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "api/all",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "du_id" },
            { "data": "site_id" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "submission_end_time" },
            { "data": "region" },
            { "data": '<a href="'+"id"+'"></a>' }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '<a href="#" "email me">id</a>' for row 0, column 5. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, one is by using [defaultContent](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent), or you can use [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) which gives more flexibility I think:

```
{ "data": "submission_end_time" },
{ "data": "region" },
{
    'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<a href="'+ data +'"></a>';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "{{url('api/all')}}",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "du_id" },
            { "data": "site_id" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "submission_end_time" },
            { "data": "region" },
            { "data": "id"  ,  "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Action</a>';
    }}
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: its still now working in my columns section i have the put the render like this https://pastebin.com/emkwet3j. i am getting error Request unknown Parameter 'alink' rows 0 column 3