# Update Datatable response before adding to Datable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using server side rendering for my data table now i want to alter the data i am getting from the json.

Here is what i want to do

```
ajax:({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },

                type: "GET",
                url: '{{ url('admin/getLogData') }}'+goURI,

                "dataSrc": function(json) {

                    var return_data = new Array();
                    for(var i=0;i< json.data.length; i++){
                        //console.log(json[i].conversion_id);
                        //console.log(json.data[i].audit_type);
                        if(json.data['i'].audit_type=='text'){
                            var lnk='<a href={{ url('admin/text/view/') }}/'+ json.data[i].text_id + '>' + json.data[i].text_name +'</a>';
                        }
                        if(json.data['i'].audit_type=='msg'){
                            var lnk='<a href={{ url('admin/msg/view') }}/'+ json.data[i].msg_id + '>' + json.data[i].msg_company + '</a>';
                        }
                        if(json.data['i'].audit_type=='view'){
                            var lnk='<a href={{ url('admin/view/view') }}/'+ json.data[i].view_id + '>' + json.data[i].view_company + '</a>';
                        }

                        return_data.push({

                            'aID': json.data[i].audit_id,
                            'dTime': json.data[i].created_at,
                            'aType': json.data[i].audit_type,
                            'alink'  :  lnk,
                            'aUser'  : '<a href=mailto:'+ json.data[i].email +'>' + json.data[i].name + ' - ' + json.data[i].email + '</a>',
                            'aAct': '<a class=nyroModal href={{ url('admin/getAuditLog') }}/' + json.data[i].audit_id + '>view</a>',

                        })
                    }
                    return return_data;
                }

            })
```

if you see i want to update the value of lnk variable according the response i am getting from the AJAX. But i am getting undefined audit_type error.

Can any one help on how can i fix this?

Comment: This is not what `dataSrc` is for.  I can see that you've copied the example [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) code, but if you actually _read_ the documentation, it states  **"(note this can, should, be done using render for the column - this is just a simple example of how the data can be manipulated)"**. So I suggest you do what it says and use `render`, here's an example: [stackoverflow.com/questions/45030098](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030098)

Comment: But i wont be able to user other variable with the render function only the audit_type will be accessible for the render function

Comment: Which other variable do you mean? If it's returned in the json, it will be available in the render function.

Comment: Will i able to this? https://pastebin.com/U8KxsTKE

Comment: What does your json data look like?

Comment: @markpsmith check here https://pastebin.com/n7rCcsFy
if the audit_type is msg then in my datable i want to show the link to that msg and if the value is view then the link should go to view

Answer (score 0):

The [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function allows you to manipulate the json before it is displayed. Critically, the `full` parameter represents the whole row of data, so you can access all elements by index.

```
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    if(full[2]=='text'){
        return '<a href={{ url('admin/text/view') }}/'+ full[10] + '>' + full[11] + '</a>';
    }
    if(full[2]=='msg'){
        return '<a href={{ url('admin/msg/view/') }}/'+ full[8] + '>' + full[9] +'</a>';
    }
    if(full[2]=='view'){
        return '<a href={{ url('admin/view/view') }}/'+ full[6] + '>' + full[7] + '</a>';
    }
}
```